# non-root user starts process belonging to cgroup owned by root

Tags: linux, cgroups

I create a non-root user and then run a simple bash (it just sleeps). However, the process started by that user belongs to a cgroup owned by root. This makes me failing to move the process to the cgroup owned by that non-root user. How can a non-root user move the process to cgroup owned by them?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. It's cgroup v2.

```
bash main.sh &
[1] 2061
ps aux | grep main.sh | grep -v grep
user0       2061  0.0  0.6   7760  3336 pts/0    S+   03:46   0:00 bash main.sh
cat /proc/2061/cgroup
0::/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope
ls -l /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice | grep session-3.scope
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  0 Apr 13 03:45 session-3.scope
```

Here is how I create the cgroup.

```
sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup0
sudo chown -R user0:user0 /sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup0
```

I get permission denied when I move the process.

```
echo "2061" > /sys/fs/cgroup/myGroup0/cgroup.procs
-bash: echo: write error: Permission denied
```